# Must a virtually abelian group surject onto the integers?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated, infinite, virtually abelian group; that is,

- $G$ is infinite, but
- there is a finite set $X\subseteq G$ generating $G$, and
- there exists abelian $H\leq G$ with $[G:H]<\infty$.

Does there exist a surjective homomorphism $f\in G\to\mathbb{Z}$?

<s>I ask because a key claim in [Tao's proof](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/a-proof-of-gromovs-theorem/) of Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth is that such a homomorphism exists (for $G$ a subset of a compact Lie group — I don't know if this matters).</s>  (Having reread the post, Tao does not make that claim; I am still interested in the question, though).  And yet it is not obvious to me, nor can I think of a counterexample.

I can prove the claim when $G$ is virtually central (i.e., $[G:Z(G)]<\infty$).  For: since $G$ is infinite but $[G:Z(G)]$ is not, so must $Z(G)$ be.  In any group, $Z(G)$ injects into the abelianization $G^\text{ab}=G/[G,G]$.  Of course, there are infinite abelian groups with no direct factor of infinite order (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$), but none are finitely generated.  And $G^\text{ab}$ is finitely generated by $X^\text{ab}$.

Now, $$H/[G,H]\subseteq Z(G/[G,H])$$ so that $G/[G,H]$ is virtually central, but it isn't clear to me that $Z(G/[G,H])$ should be an infinite group anymore.

Comment: Are you familiar with the infinite dihedral group?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Of course!  Now I feel stupid.  I guess I tunnel-visioned a little that it had to be true.  If you write that up as an answer within the next few days, I'll accept.  (After that point, I'll write it up myself.)

Comment: The correct result is that $G$ either surjects to ${\mathbb Z}$ or to $D_\infty$, the infinite dihedral group. I will write a proof later.

Comment: @MoisheKohan this is false (I guess it's a confusion since it's true for virtually cyclic groups, a result of Wall). If $C$ is a subgroup of order 3 in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ then $\mathbf{Z}^2\rtimes C$ has neither $\mathbf{Z}$ nor $D_\infty$ as quotient.

Comment: @YCor I was writing about virtually cyclic groups, somehow I forgot to mention this.

Comment: In general, any torsion-free (non-trivial) supersoluble group surjects onto either $\mathbb Z$ or $D_\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moishe Kohan points out in the comments, the infinite dihedral group $$D_{\infty}=\langle\rho,\sigma:\sigma^2=1,\sigma\rho\sigma=\rho^{-1}\rangle$$ is a counterexample.

The group $D_{\infty}$ is infinite and finitely generated, with index-$2$ abelian subgroup $\langle\rho\rangle$.  But the commutator subgroup of $D_{\infty}$ is $\langle\rho^2\rangle$, so that $D_{\infty}$ has finite abelianization.

More generally, let $V$ be any infinite abelian group generated by finite $S$ and let finite $G\leq\mathrm{Aut}(V)$ act on $V$ such that, for any $s\in S$, there exists $T\in G$ and $v\in V$ with $Tv=v+s$ (in fancy language: as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, $V$ is trivial modulo the augmentation ideal).  Then consider the semidirect product $H=V\rtimes G$.  $H$ is then infinite, virtually abelian, and finitely generated.  For any $v\in V$ and $T\in G$, we have $$TvT^{-1}v^{-1}=Tv-v$$  Thus then $V\subseteq[H,H]$, so that $H^\text{ab}$ is finite.

Comment: Kohan claims that any counterexample must surject to $D_{\infty}$.  I would prefer a answer that proves such a claim, but I don't see how to do so.

Comment: As indicated in a comment to the question, there are easy counterexamples not surjecting onto $D_\infty$.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks; I'll incorporate that into this answer.